# Building SoundCloudAPI Fails with Apple Mach-O Librarian Error

Tags: soundcloud, ios-frameworks

I'm trying to integrate SoundCloud sharing into my project using the instructions at https://github.com/soundcloud/CocoaSoundCloudAPI. In my workspace, OHAttributedLabel, OAuth2Client, JSONKit and SoundCloudUI all build fine, but building SoundCloudAPI for iOS always fails with the following errors:

> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool: can't locate file for: -lSoundCloudAPI
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool: file: -lSoundCloudAPI is not an object file (not allowed in a library)
>   Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool failed with exit code 1

Does anyone know what's going on here?

Comment: Have you tried the [demo project](https://github.com/soundcloud/CocoaSoundCloudDemo)?

Comment: Yes, I get the same error, as well as the error 'SCUI.h' file not found.

Comment: Had very similar problem. Hope it can be solved.